# Styling Html5 Canvas Inner Text Shadow

Tags: html, html5-canvas

Could anyone come up with a quick sample of inner-shadoewed text? I've white div, which hosts gray a shadowed canvas, the former should have inner-shadoewed text in white.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is a bit cryptic. But maybe you want to change the shadow color of your text.
in your CSS try:

```
text-shadow: rgb(255, 255, 255) 0px 0px 5px 0px;
```